# How to use Hilt for NavController in screens?

Tags: dependency-injection, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have this code as below:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "records")  {
    composable("records") { RecordsScreen(navController)) }
    ......
```

Indeed, I have more screens which need navController. Currently I have to pass it as parameter of each screen.

Do we have a method to use Hilt to implement the DI so that I don't need to pass the parameter for each screen? If I create a module to provide the instance of NavController, where should I instantiate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hilt Navigation.

Info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation

Your code would look something like this:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "records")  {
    composable("records") { 
        val viewModel = hiltViewModel<RecordsViewModel>(it)
        RecordsScreen(viewModel)
    }
    composable(
        "detail",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument(ID_ARG) {
                type = NavType.LongType
            }
        )
     ) { 
        val viewModel = hiltViewModel<DetailViewModel>(it)
        DetailScreen(viewModel)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may not need to set the navController parameter for many `@Composable` functions. If your situation is like this, you may want to lift the navController state.

```
@Composable
fun A(navController: NavController) { B(navController) }

@Composable
fun B(navController: NavController) { C(navController) }

@Composable
fun C(navController: NavController) { navController.navigate(...) }
```

If that's the case, it would be a better choice to lift the navigate behavior of C as a lambda parameter. It would look something like this:

```
@Composable
fun A(navController: NavController) { B(navigate = navController.navigate(...)) }

@Composable
fun B(navigate:() -> Unit) { C(navigate = navigate) }

@Composable
fun C(navigate:() -> Unit) { 
  Button(onClick = navigate) { } 
}
```

If you find this approach uncomfortable, you can also avoid using Hilt to instantiate `navController` and instead use `CompositionLocalProvider` to provide your `navController`.

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalNavController provides navController) {
  NavHost(navController = navController)  {
    ...
  }
}


val LocalNavController = compositionLocalOf<NavController> {
  error("CompositionLocal LocalNavController not present")
}
```

Then you can directly get the same instance of navController in your C.

```
@Composable
fun A() { B() }

@Composable
fun B() { C() }

@Composable
fun C() { 
  val navController = LocalNavController.current
  Button(onClick = navController.navigate(...)) { } 
}
```